# Scala DSL - implicit methods of a function object

Tags: scala, dsl

In my DSL I want to be able to do like this:

```
val a = 5

Parse("TYPE") {
  a match {
    case 3 => info("almost")
    case s: String => error("wrong type")
    case 5 => info("you won!")
    case _ => error("omg")
  }
}
```

with output

```
[INFO] TYPE: you won!
```

where `Parse` is a function object, which has the `apply(String)`, `info(String)` and `error(String)` methods:

```
object Parse {

  def apply(name: String)(parseF: => Unit) { parseF }
  def info(text: String) { println("[INFO] " + name + ": " + text) }
  def error(text: String) { println("[ERROR] " + name + ": " + text) }

}
```

The trick is that the output of the `info` and `error` methods should be somehow native to the `Parse` object and construct the message by the example as shown above. Therefore, they

1. have to be accessible like in the example, without any imports.
2. have to have the access to the first argument passed to `Parse()` ("TYPE" in the example).
3. must not create any instances or extra objects during their working.

This is an ideal description. I think that it will require some more boilerplate. Please suggest, how can I acheive that?

**EDIT:** my initial guess to declare the `info` and `error` methods inside the `apply` method does not make them visible in the `parseF` method being passed. Well, unsurprisingly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution that satisfies 1-3. You can have 1 and 2 or 2 and 3 with slightly different syntax.

1 and 2)

```
class Parse(val s:String) {
  def info....

}

new Parse("TYPE") {

}
```

2 and 3)

```
object Parse {
  def apply(s:String)(f:String=>Unit) = ...
}

Parse("TYPE")(s => {

})
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
object Parse {
  val currentName = new util.DynamicVariable("<none>")
  def apply(name: String)(parseF: => Unit) = currentName.withValue(name)(parseF)
  def info(text: String) = println("[INFO] %s: %s" format (currentName.value, text)
}

// usage
import Parse._ // there's no other way to get ability to call 'info' without 'Parse'.
Parse("TYPE") {
  // some code
  info("some info") // prints: [INFO] TYPE: some info
}

info("some other info") // prints: [INFO] <none>: some other info
```

If needed, it's easy to make `info` throw exception if it is called outside `Parse {}` block.